# Combining Altium BOM items and updating parameters

Tags: components, altium, bom

I'm having a hard time working with Altium's BOM management - here's my issue:  I'm using general components like the shown 0402 capacitor part used in hundreds of places across the schematic.  In these, there are issues with individual parameters (incomplete description, etc) on some of these parts.  Ideally I'd like to group these parts together and update their parameters together, because it would literally take a week of copying and pasting to do this one by one with the schematic sheet.

The ActiveBOM seems like a good way to organize this, but I'm running into problems.  I cannot seem to update any of the parameters in the parts listed without finding each one in the schematic.  In the screenshot shown below, some of the descriptions of the same type of part are incomplete and show up as different parts entirely, despite being grouped by part number.

I clearly am working in a way that Altium has not intended.  Can anybody point me in the right direction for cleaning up my BOM?

[image: ActiveBOM screenshot]

Comment: I take it you don't want to/can't smart search and update from the properties tab?

Comment: Just read up on this feature.  A bit more clunky than I was imagining, but this definitely works.  Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: It appears that this only works within the open schematic sheet...better than nothing, but still seems like there must be a better way

Comment: The last time I checked, "Parameter Manager" allows you to modify component parameters all at once.  Also makes it easy to find those pesky parts that are slightly different, and fix them too. (schematic Menu bar)

Comment: Aha!  This looks promising.  I knew there would be something silly I was missing.

Comment: For your next design, make separate component library entries for each real part. You can use the Manufacturer Part Search to import the parts with parametric data, then copy-paste the symbol from an existing part and assign a generic footprint (0805, 0603, 0402, etc.) if it's just a resistor, cap, chip inductor, or whatever. It's a bit of work to get your library built but it saves a ton of work in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

Look in to using the *Update Parameters From Database* (found in the tools menu, keyboard shortcut T D) which is equivalent to Orcad's Include file technique. This requires Microsoft Office to be installed. If you don't have Office installed, then install the Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable. This technique is fine for individuals, but much harder to maintain for many users. Refer to Altium's online manuals to implement this.

You create an Excel database file with the parts you are using. Altium will field match certain fields like *library reference* and *value* and stuff the parameters of your choice (perhaps footprint, description, manufacturer part number, manufacturer, and your company part number) to each schematic part.

An example of an Excel spreadsheet. 
Library reference and value are part of the component parameters in your schematic that you entered.
The rest of the items (footprint, description, Mfgr_pn, Manufacturer, Company_pn) are stuffed in to the matching parts using the Update Parameters from Database tool.

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline Library Reference & Value & Footprint & Description & Mfg\_PN & Manufacturer & Company\_PN \\ \hline R0402 & 10.0 & R0402 & RESISTOR, 10.0, 1\% & ERJ2RKF10R0X & PANASONIC & 110010R0 \\ \hline LT3094 & LT3094 & LCC12.3X3mm & NEG \;REGULATOR & LT3094EDD & ANALOG DEVICES & 22000124 \\ \hline  \end{array}